# How to Scale numbers/values

Tags: math

I am working with a piece of hardware that I'm communicating with VIA serial control using a proprietary programming language that looks like a very dumbed down version of C.

The device reports it's current volume when queried. The range is -60 to + 20. How do I scale that to a 0-255 range which goes up in increments of 3?

Can you also provide an example of another value and other scale i.e. -15 to 15 scaled to 0-165, etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To scale a range x0..x1 to a new range y0..y1:

```
    y = y0 + (y1 - y0) * (x - x0) / (x1 - x0)
```

So for your first example above, x0 = -60, x1 = 20, y0 = 0, y1 = 255:

```
    y = 0 + (255 - 0) * (x - -60) / (20 - -60)

=>  y = 255 * (x + 60) / 80
```

Answer (score 9):

This is actually simple maths

First, let's remove the need of a negative number :

For range -60 <-> + 20 : x + 60

Now we have a 0 <-> 80 range, just scale it to 255 : ( x / 80 ) * 255

Put that all in a formula, and this is what you should get : 
y = ( (x + 60 ) / 80 ) * 255

So basically :

y = ( (x + negativeValue ) / MaxValue ) * MaxScale

I hope you understand now !

Comment: Great explanation. I would add to "scale it to 255 : ( x / 80 ) * 255" that the division by 80 takes the range from 0 <-> 80 to 0 <-> 1. Whatever you multiply that by will be scaled as a percentage.